# Gitlab installing tiller using helm is giving kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com not a valid chart repository

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I am using `GitLab v12.9.1`

I have created a local `kubernetes` cluster using `microk8`.

My `GitLab` instance is successfully configured with the `kubernetes` instance.

When I am installing helm using the `GitLab` then it is giving error
[image]

I checked the `tiller pod` logs using

```
kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps logs install-helm
```

The logs output is

```
+ helm init --tiller-tls --tiller-tls-verify --tls-ca-cert /data/helm/helm/config/ca.pem --tiller-tls-cert /data/helm/helm/config/cert.pem --tiller-tls-key /data/helm/helm/config/key.pem --service-account tiller
Creating /root/.helm 
Creating /root/.helm/repository 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /root/.helm/plugins 
Creating /root/.helm/starters 
Creating /root/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /root/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Error: error initializing: Looks like "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:60799->127.0.0.53:53: read: connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can check on [Ping Test](https://tools.keycdn.com/ping), `kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com` is a reliable address.

So, cause may be either due to [GFW](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/1171) or due to local connectivity issues.

### In case of `GFW` try a mirror

For the first case WA would be to replace the charts repo URL with mirror like https://kubernetes.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/charts.

### In local connectivity cases try repository cache

For the second case you may try to use local cache, i.e.:

~/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
repositories:
- caFile: ""
  cache: ~/.helm/repository/cache/stable-index.yaml
  certFile: ""
  keyFile: ""
  name: stable
  password: ""
  url: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
  username: ""
- caFile: ""
  cache: ~/.helm/repository/cache/local-index.yaml
  certFile: ""
  keyFile: ""
  name: local
  password: ""
  url: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
  username: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because of the firewall.
You can solve this by specify your stable-repo-url:

```
helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 100 --wait --stable-repo-url=<your url, such as https://kubernetes.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/charts>
```